# Gem install rails installing me an empty directory

Tags: windows-7, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-1.9.3

I'm trying to install the updated version of rails, but after a bit I understood that the problem is that gem install rails is installing me an empty directory.

Notice that I didn't have any problem previously, I installed all rails versions correctly though gem install, don't know what happened this time.

Anyone can tell me what's happening and how to and how to solve this?

I have devkit installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just reinstalled everythings, seems the only way to fix.
I didn't understood the problem actually.

If anyone has a better answer, please post it.